# Algorithm for extracting a subarray out of an integer array, which contains the maximum summation

Tags: java, javascript, c++, c, algorithm

There is an array of integers (both positive and negative). Please, advice an algorithm which will give you the subarray with maximum sum.
Example:

```
int a[] = new int[]{2,3,-1,4,5,7,8,13,-20};
```

then the answer should be `{4,5,7,8,13}` as `4 + 5 + 7 + 8 + 13 = 37`.

I am unable to design the algorithm for this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to subset from a certain amount of numbers?

Comment: Without additional constraints it's trivial. Just add all positive elements of the array. If there is no positives the sum is 0 (empty subset) or single maximal element (1 element subset) depending on requirements. But it that case it's unclear why {2, 3} are excluded from result. Maybe you mean sub sequence of **ordered** array?

Comment: Jarlax:  Assum of {2,3} is 5. But the sum of {4,5,7,8,13} is 37 and 37 > 5.

Comment: Why are you including all these languages? You are interested in the pseudocode? An what have you tried so far?

Comment: You started from index 3 and on is that what you want?

Comment: @PraveenKumar If `a` is set, {2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 13} is valid subset with maximal sum 42.

Comment: Eypros I tried with Java code. I am happy if direction comes for any language. Pseudocode is ok for me.

Comment: Jarlax subset should be in continuous order.

Comment: Oh ok I just read what you want hold on

Comment: @PraveenKumar Then it is [maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)

Comment: what about zeros those included?

Comment: If the chosen subset can't contain any gaps then it's something more specific than a subset.  I would call it a *substring* or *block* or *subarray*.  Update your question.

Comment: Whats with all the languages if this is an *algorithm* question ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar did you see my answer the variable `sum == 42`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a linear solution to this problem:

```
long getMaximumSubarraySum(int[] a) {
    int start = 0; 
    int end = 0;
    long result = 0; // I assume that an empty subarray is allowed.
    long minPrefixSum = 0;
    int minPrefixSumPos = -1;
    long currentPrefixSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        currentPrefixSum += a[i];
        if (currentPrefixSum - minPrefixSum > result) {
             result = currentPrefixSum - minPrefixSum;
             start = minPrefixSumPos + 1;
             end = i + 1;
        }
        if (currentPrefixSum < minPrefixSum) {
             minPrefixSum = currentPrefixSum;
             minPrefixSumPos = i;
        }
    }
    // The resulting subarray is [start; end).
    return result;
}
```

The idea behind this algorithm is very simple: let's take a look at prefix sums. Then the answer is the maximum value of `max(prefixSum[i] - prefixSum[j])`, where `j < i` for all `i`. That's exactly what this code does: it iterates over the input array, maintains the current prefix sum and the minimum prefix sum and chooses the best answer.

Comment: Small comments. The question was how to retrieve sub-array itself, not the sum. Also your code allows zero-length sub-arrays (which may or may not be acceptable).

Comment: @Jarlax I modified the code so that it also finds the subarray itself. A zero-lenght subarray looks natural here because otherwise the question is: what should we do if `a` is empty?

Comment: Thanks @Jarlax as I was unaware of Maximum subarray problem. One request, if possible, could you please provide more links which has the similar problems.

Comment: @PraveenKumar The algorithm itself is described on Wikipedia really well. For practice you may consider next problems on [UVA](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/): [507](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=448), [787](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=728), [10684](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=1625).

Answer (score 0):

A few months back I had solved this problem, so I am going to provide you the algo. It's upto you to write the program.

The main point of the program is that the sum decreases when you encounter a negetive number in the array. So when that happens, you divide the array into 3 parts. 
**1) Sum till now**
**2) Sum till now + the negetive value(or values if there are continuous negetive numbers)**
**3) (2) + the sum till you encounter another negetive number**
Given these 3 parts, choose the part with the maximum value and store it in a variable. This value becomes the **(1)** for your next iteration. Continue till you reach the end of array

Here's the pseudo-code:

```
 do until end of array{
        b=compute_b() //Compute sum till you encounter negetive number
        c=compute_c() //Compute sum till you encounter a positive number
        a=max+b+c;
        if(a>c)
        {
             if(a>max)
             {
                      max=a;
             }
         }
         else
         {
              if(c>max)
              {
                    max=c;
              }
          }
    }
    print max
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = [2,3,-1,4,5,7,8,13,-20];
var positiveNums =  a.filter(function(num){
  return num > 0
}); // [2,3,4,5,7,8,13]
var sum = positiveNums.reduce(function(a, b){
  return a+b;
}); // 42
```

Comment: cut is not a function it's an array my bad perhaps this fix will be better
@RiggsFolly